# The Safari app has disappeared from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I can't find the safari icon on my iphone 4?  I have tried resetting home screen layout and that doesn't work.  My restrictions button is 'on' and it asks for a password for this button.  I don't have a password.  Can you help? Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have got restrictions turned on, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it is these restrictions that are causing you an issue, you could have turned these on long ago and forgotten what password was setup (for sure, *someone* has turned this on and a password is required as part of this process).

If the missing safar is due to restrictions, then there is simply no choice other than recalling the password, or *possibly* restoring the phone from an old backup on the chance that the backup pre-dates the turning on of restrictions.

But icons often go missing for other reasons due to a particularly mean bug.  You can reset your homescreen layout to restore missing icons when this happens, (warning, it will reset the location and grouping of *all* your icons when you do this) by going to  Settings > Reset > Reset Home Screen Layout.

One final note, you may have simply moved it somewhere daft into a folder or something by accident - can you find Safari in Spotlight search?

Answer (score 0):

Since the restrictions are turned on, Its highly possible that someone turned safari off, and set the restriction.
Find out who used your phone other than you before safari went off, and ask them to put in the password.

The resolutions is what Stuffe suggested. You will have to reset your phone to factory condition. Take a backup. 
refer https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2667637?start=15&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is jail broken and you have the "dockshift" tweak, remove it and your missing icons should be revealed where your dock was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

All I did was turn my restrictions off then on and there it was on my last page of my apps. Simple solution for me. And believe me it was not there. I was using Google for iPhone and it sucks big time.

Answer (score 0):

I started up an old 3GS today. There was no Safari as icon anywhere. I could start Safari from search.

Restrictions were turned off.
I switched on restrictions. Then I switched off Safari in restrictions.
And then I switched Safari back on in restrictions. This resolved the problem, the icon reappeared.

This is iOS version 6x. I am now using this phone with an old Logitech soundbox for listening to internet radios.

Answer (score -1):

I asked Siri to search something. Then I selected it. Returned to my home screen and there it was again!!