# Safari has disappeared from my iPhone 6

Tags: safari

Safari is NOT on my iPhone 6 anywhere. It is not in a folder as I have not put any extra folders on it. I also do not have the use of Spotlight. Cannot figure this out.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97983/the-safari-app-has-disappeared-from-my-iphone might give a clue

Answer (score 1):

You turned on Restrictions.  Turn it off again.